# How to apply $watchCollection to grid in template(html page) that is included using ng-include in another page?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angularjs

I am new to angularJS.

I have a page that contains a grid filled with data.

```
<table items="personList" tr-ng-grid page-items="9"
   selection-mode="SingleRow" selected-items="personGrid"
   style="font-size: smaller;">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th field-name="Name" display-name="{{ 'settings_grid_name' | translate }}"></th>
    <th field-name="address" display-name="{{ 'settings_grid_address' | translate }}"></th>
    <th field-name="age" display-name="{{ 'settings_grid_age' | translate }}"></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td field-name="age">
            <div class="text-center">
                <i style="font-size: 21px" class="base-icon {{getDeviceState(gridItem.age)}}"></i>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td field-name="address">
            <div class="text-center">
                <i style="font-size: 21px" ng-style="getDeviceColor(gridItem.Id, gridItem.Status)" class="base-icon {{getDeviceIconType(gridItem.address)}}"></i>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

**Controller code**

```
$scope.$watchCollection('personGrid', function (newVal, oldVal) {

            console.log('Working -- New value');
            console.log(newVal);


        });
```

I had applied $watchCollection in controller,  when i select any single row it fires the $watchCollection event and all works fine.

**I had use the above template in another new hmtl page.**

```
 <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2">
    <div ng-include="'settingsModule/views/settingsModuleVehicleGrid.tpl.html'"></div>
</div>
```

**And code in controller used for  new html page.**

```
 $scope.$parent.$watchCollection('personGrid', function (newVal, oldVal) {

            console.log('Working --');
            console.log(newVal);
        });
```

But they event is only fired when page load first time. after that when i select any row in table grid , the event is not fired. : (

Any help, some better solution. May be we can add the data in $rootScope and apply $watch.